# iperf bandwidth; what is the difference between -b 60m and -b 60M

Tags: iperf

I am using iperf and have the following problem

1. iperf ... -b 60M, I have 12% packet loss
2. iperf ... -b 60m, I have 0.2% packet loss

In both of  these cases, the bandwidth is 60 Mbit/s

### 0.0-10.0 sec 71.0 MBytes 59.6 Mbits/sec 0.150 ms 0/50661 (0%)

What is the difference between -b 60m and -b 60M ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after hours of searching:
m = 1000*1000 bit
M = 1024*1024 bit

I have problem with searching for interpreting the result of iperf ( I am doing testing on boards and sometimes the result do not follow ordinary patterns).
Does anyone knows of any good website or document?